# terminology for class objects related by composition

Tags: c++, terminology, composition

```
class C {
private:
    int j;
};

class B {
private:
    C c;
};

class A {
private:
    B b;
};

A a;
```

I'm wondering what the correct terminology for a composition hierarchy in C++:

- what is `b` to `c`, and vice-versa?
- what is `a` to `c`, and vice-versa?

I'd be tempted to use terms like child, parent, root, base, sub-object, etc, but these seem to usually refer to an inheritance relationship or are ambiguous. "Contained object" seems OK (albeit a bit clunky), but in the other direction I can't say "container" (already refers to a vector, map etc). Is there any succinct and conventional way to describe the relationships?

Comment: `C` is a data member of `B`?

Comment: This program won't compile because class `B` uses incomplete type as its field.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it compiles to answer the question does it? I'm just interested in the terminology. Anyway, I added some code to make ``C`` a complete class :D

Comment: A is C's second cousin, twice removed on the mother's side.

Comment: You can say "containing object" instead of "container".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is taken from the exelent synopsis of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a

## What is `b` to `c`?

`c` is a "meronym" or "constituent" of `b`. This is a "part-of" relationship.

## What is `c` to `b`?

`b` is a "member" of `c` or `b` is "composed" of `c`. This is a "has-a" relationship.

## What is `a` to `c`, and vice-versa?

Object-oriented terms for talking about jumping two levels of hierarchy are incongruent, though "grandchild", "grandparent", or "intermediate class" may be thrown around.

In this particular case it would be fair to say that `c` is a "meronym of `a`'s member" or "constituent of `a`'s member". And that "`a`'s member is composed of `c`".

But in either case you're really just trying to describe that hierarchy.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I like "constituent", that is very clear. It seems there are more-established terms for multilevel inheritance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Types_of_inheritance) than multilevel composition. Maybe it's because people use inheritance a lot more often.

Comment: @JohnnyLyco That is actually fair, I have heard the term intermediate class in C++ spec, so I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: I think the answer of "What is c to b?" is correct, but not exactly what was asked, right?    Yes, b is "composed" of c, but I think what is needed here is more of a noun (like we have with the parent/child relationship).   Is c then the "composer?"  (It's not a term found readily with a search.)   Do we have such a term?   If not, should we coin one?  What does one call the thing a group of constituents constitute?

Comment: @user3761340 Sorry I should have added the noun form for consistency, this is a very well agreed on term, `b` is a "member" of `c`. I've updated the answer to reflect that.